# Zener Diode maximum current calculation based on max rated Power dissapation

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, zener

[image: Zener Diode Question]
Question as in picture part 3 a)

Do I calculate the maximum current based of the slope resistance of 1 ohm and Pmax 3W (I squared R)

Or do I calculate the the maximum current based on the 15V zener and Pmax 3W (VI)

Other examples in the course seem to point to using VI but if you apply Kirchoff's Voltage Law to the loop and include the slope resistance it obviously does not equate. On the other hand if you were to use (I squared R) to solve then the max current= 1.73A which seems excessive.

Can someone please help solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Equate power ( 3 watts)  to the sum of 15*I plus I*I*1. This then gives a quadratic equation and solve for I.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I have actually just worked it out before I saw your answer. I managed to solve without using a quadratic but your answer is accurate thank you.

Comment: I=P/V=3/15=0.2, Rz=1ohm, V=IR=1x0.2=0.2, Vz+Vrz=15.2, Vs-(Vz+Vrz)=14.98v, R=V/I=14.98/0.2=74.9ohms.

Comment: I am equipped with only an android phone, pen and paper and get 197 mA as pretty close. Is this what you got? This also means that the max output voltage is 15.197 volts.